# @react-native-community/google-signin standalone app don´t work

Tags: android, react-native, google-signin

i´m using @react-native-community/google-signin working good on debug mode, but don´t work on android release mode (standalone app).

I already tried what it says in the documentation and nothing.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android
https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin

Can anybody help me...

I did the credentials OAuth 2.0 Client IDs width SHA-1 from my keystore release.

This my code

```
const signIn = async () => {
    try {
      GoogleSignin.configure({
        scopes: ['email', 'profile'], 
        webClientId: webClient
        offlineAccess: true, 
        forceCodeForRefreshToken: true,
        accountName: ''
     });

      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      const isSignedIn = await GoogleSignin.isSignedIn();
      if(isSignedIn){
        await GoogleSignin.revokeAccess();
        await GoogleSignin.signOut();
      }
     
     
      const respLogGoogle = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
     
      const responseLogBack = 
        await dispatch(authActions.loginSocials(
          respLogGoogle.user.email,
          respLogGoogle.user.name,
          respLogGoogle.user.photo
        ))
      ;

     
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
        // user cancelled the login flow
        console.log('Cancel');
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
        console.log('Signin in progress');
        // operation (f.e. sign in) is in progress already
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
        console.log('PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE');
        // play services not available or outdated
      } else {
        // some other error happened
         console.log("GOOGLE:",error);
      }
    }
  };
```

Gradle Properties

```
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE='KeyStore.keystore'
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS='keyAlias'
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD='*********'
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD='='*********''
```

Build gradle

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('KeyStore.keystore')) {
                storeFile file('KeyStore.keystore')
                storePassword '*******'
                keyAlias 'keyAlias'
                keyPassword '*********'
            }
        }
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    /* signingConfigs {
       
    } */
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own    keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

**Thanks**

Comment: Provide more info on how you used it, code samples on how you implemented the said package, what you have tried and such. We are not magicians here

Comment: Oh sorry, i did it!